# Python Regex String

Tags: python, regex, expression

Homework exercise:
Insert the regex string (just the string) which will match any number of ones and zeros (even no ones and zeros) followed by exactly three zeroes.  For example for the string,

```
"101000100 00101000 1010 1000"
```

your regex pattern should give the three matches (using findall()):

```
['101000', '00101000', '1000']
```

My answer was:

```
r"[10]*1000"
```

but it doesn't seem to be the answer they want. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your regex has `1000` in the end instead of `000`

Comment: Did you try any tests?

Comment: Yeh I did. There are a few methods that give the right answer. The problem was actually in the way I was entering my answer. Just had to input: "[10]*0{3}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
>>> s = "101000100 00101000 1010 1000"
>>> m = re.findall(r"\b[10]*?000\b", s)
>>> m
['101000', '00101000', '1000']
```

- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `[10]*?` Match 0 or 1 zero or more times (Shortest possible match).
- `000` Exactly three 0's.
- `\b` And the matched 0's must be followed by a word boundary.

Comment: This was a homework question I think, OP just needed some guidance to fix his/her regex

Comment: Thanks that explains it well.